# Cannot login through Facebook in Laravel 5.1

Tags: facebook, laravel, authentication

I am trying to login with facebook using Laravel 5.1.

I am following each steps mention in laravel documentation. 
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication.

But, When i login through facebook then it will redirect to my normal login page.
In sort Session is store in facebook login.

This is a Code that is written by me.

**Router.php**

```
Route::get('auth/facebook','Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback','Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**AuthController.php**

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return  Socialite::driver('facebook')
            ->scopes(['email', 'public_profile'])
            ->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();
    $user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();
    // OAuth Two Providers
    $token = $user->token;
    // OAuth One Providers
    $token = $user->token;
    $tokenSecret = $user->tokenSecret;
    // All Providers
    $user->getId();
    $user->getNickname();
    $user->getName();
    $user->getEmail();
    $user->getAvatar();
}
```

**Services.php**

```
 'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '1625567400000000',
    'client_secret' => 'secret',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/',
 ],
```

When i type localhost/8000/auth/facebook it will redirect me to facebook and ask permission for public_profile, email etc.
And it will redirect back to localhost/auth/login.

And when i type localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback in URL, it will through error like this;

ClientException in Middleware.php line 69:

Client error: 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, I guest you are using middleware to check if the user is already logged in. And this might the problem that you get redirect to `localhost/auth/login`

I hope following code could be useful to you

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{        
    //retrieve user's information from facebook
    $socUser  = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    //check user already exists in db
    $user = \App\User::where('email', $socUser->getEmail())->first();
    if($user) {
        // if exist, log user into your application
        //  and redirect to any path you want
        \Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->route('user.index');
    }

    //if not exist, create new user, 
    // log user into your application 
    // and resirect to any path you want
    $user = new \App\User ;
    $user->email = $socUser->getEmail();
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    $user->save();
    \Auth::login($user); // login user
    return redirect()->route('user.index'); // redirect
}
```

note: I did not test my code but you should get some idea

for more information: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

and as @mimo mention,

> Your redirect url in the Services.php file has to be
>
> localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect url in the Services.php file has to be

```
localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback
```

Comment: mimo:    I am getting same error after changing in services.php file.

Comment: You should not manually call the URL. Before you send someone to Facebook for authentication laravel will store a session. When the user comes back the session will be used. For security reasons it's not possible to call the URL again.

Comment: I changed redirect URL of facebook APP and Services.php both to http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback.

But i am still getting same error.